# Bootstrap input file field doesn't show right on Safari only

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The Bootstrap file input field on Safari doesn't show correctly.

With IE, Chrome and FF:

> [image: Good]

And with Safari:

> [image: Bad]

Any ideas why ?

Bootstrap version is 3.3.1

Below is the css file I use for this upload field. All the rest of my bootstrap is working properly on Safari. There is just this one field that doesn't show right.

fileinput.css:

```
    /*!
 * @copyright Copyright &copy; Kartik Visweswaran, Krajee.com, 2015
 * @package bootstrap-fileinput
 * @version 4.1.6
 *
 * File input styling for Bootstrap 3.0
 * Built for Yii Framework 2.0
 * Author: Kartik Visweswaran
 * Year: 2015
 * For more Yii related demos visit http://demos.krajee.com
 */
.file-input {
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.file-loading {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 999px;
    text-align: right;
    color: #fff;
    background: transparent url('../img/loading.gif') top left no-repeat;
    border: none;
}
.btn-file {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-file input[type=file] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    cursor: inherit;
    display: block;
}

.file-caption .glyphicon {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 18px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.file-caption-name {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.file-caption-ellipsis {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    margin-top: -6px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    display: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: default;
}

.kv-search-container .kv-search-clear {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    right: 0px;
}
.file-error-message {
    background-color: #f2dede;
    color: #a94442;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.file-caption-disabled {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    opacity: 1;
}

.file-input .btn[disabled], .file-input .btn .disabled {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.file-preview {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.file-preview-frame {
    display: table;
    margin: 8px;
    height: 160px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px #a2958a;
    padding: 6px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.file-preview-frame:hover {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px #333;
}

.file-preview-image {
    height: 160px;
    vertical-align: text-center;
}

.file-preview-text {
    width: 160px;
    color: #428bca;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
}

.file-preview-other {
    padding-top: 48px;
    text-align: center;
}

.file-preview-other i {
    font-size: 2.4em;
}
.file-other-error { 
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    text-align:right
}
.file-input-new .file-preview, .file-input-new .close, .file-input-new .glyphicon-file, 
.file-input-new .fileinput-remove-button, .file-input-new .fileinput-upload-button,
.file-input-ajax-new .fileinput-remove-button, .file-input-ajax-new .fileinput-upload-button  {
    display: none;
}

.loading {
    background: transparent url('../img/loading.gif') no-repeat scroll center center content-box !important;
}

.wrap-indicator {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #245269;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.file-actions {
    text-align: left;
}

.file-footer-buttons {
    float: right;
}

.file-thumbnail-footer .file-caption-name {
    padding-top:4px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #777;
}

.file-upload-indicator {
    padding-top: 2px;
    cursor: default;
}

.file-upload-indicator:hover {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.file-drop-zone {
    border:1px dashed #aaa;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:12px 15px 12px 12px;
    padding:5px;
}

.file-drop-zone-title {
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 85px 10px;
}

.highlighted {
    border:2px dashed #999!important;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.file-uploading {
    background-image: url('../img/loading-sm.gif');
    background-position: center bottom 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.file-icon-large {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: post your input css style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the HTML code it is very hard to find a solution for your current problem. But try this (which works on Safari as well) :

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                        Browse&hellip; <input type="file" multiple>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

and following `css`:

```
.btn-file input[type=file] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  background: red;
  cursor: inherit;
  display: block;
}
input[readonly] {
  background-color: white !important;
  cursor: text !important;
}
```

here is a preview: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVJPwZ